# Unable to POST data with foreign key relationship - Django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here are my models :

User - I am using the default User provided by django admin

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='user')
    phonenumber=models.IntegerField()
    picture=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    #dp=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    points=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.user.name)
```

Here is my View where I am trying to post the data

```
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=User.objects.all()
    serializer_class=None
    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if(self.request.method=='GET'):
            return UserSerializer
        return CreateUserSerializer

    def post(self,request,format=None):

        user=CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if(user.is_valid()):
            user.save()
```

Here is my serializer

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:

        fields=('username','password','email','userprofile')
        model=models.User      

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `User` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        userprofile = validated_data.pop('userprofile')
        instance = super(CreateUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
                profile=UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
            if profile.is_valid():
                profile.save() 
                return Response(user.data, status=201)
            return Response(user.errors, status=400)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        fields=('phonenumber','picture')
        model=models.UserProfile
    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile = super(UserProfileSerializer,self).create(validated_data)
        profile.save()
        return profile
```

User gets saved properly. Problem arises with UserProfile only. It says :

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `userprofile` on serializer `CreateUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile'.

I understand that it expects 'userprofile' inside 'user', but I had to remove it inside CreateUserSerializer for the user to get saved properly. What has to be done now? I am a newbie to django.

Answer (score 0):

Your `related_name` on `UserProfile` <-> `User` relation doesn't match field in serializer. You have `'user'` set as a related name in `ForeignKey`, but you are using `userprofile` in your serializer. Change either of those to match the other and problem should be fixed.

Comment: Ok I understand. When data is received, I get user profile details along with user.  It won't be possible to save both at the same time. My understanding is, I need to save user first followed by userprofile. But while saving user , I had to remove 'userprofile' from the validated data . How can I access that again ? Am a little confused here

Comment: The issue is not in your serializer. Those look fine. Check your models' definition, you have a different name put in `related_name` of your relation, and you're using a different one in your serializer. That causes django-rest-framework to not be able to connect those two.